# Add QR code on checkout in shopify

Tags: shopify, qr-code

I want to add a QR code in shopify which will send to client at checkout against that order. I wana know is it possible, if Yes! how?

Comment: What information will the QR code provide? It's possible to add a QR code via the notification email after the order is done, but I don't know what information you will send via that QR code and if you are OK to use the notification email for this.

Answer (score 0):

After checkout is complete, the customer is sent to a very nice thank you page. On that page are rendered the order details, and perhaps a map with fulfillment and tracking updates. That is the place you put your QR code. You can inject JS into that page, so it makes it easy for you as a developer, since you have the order details, and therefore complete control. As a bonus that page is also something the customer can permalink to, meaning it is easy for them to bookmark the page and keep in on their radar.

Comment: do they have to use Shopify Plus to do that?

Comment: No. Shopify Plus has nothing to do with that.

Comment: how do you modify that Thank you page without plus? or what is that page?

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/manual/orders/status-tracking
https://help.shopify.com/manual/orders/status-tracking#add-additional-scripts